# jQuery Datatables formatting length element

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to re align some of the elements on my jQuery datables and I'm stuck.  Ideally I'd like the Show 25 entries to all show up horizontally instead of scrunched up.  Same for the search if possible.
Here's what it looks like now:
[image]

Here's how I have the elements being placed:

```
dom: "<'myfilter'f><'mylength'l>t<'myInfo'i><'myPaging'p>",
```

and here's the CSS to move them to opposite sides of the table:

```
.myfilter .dataTables_filter {
   float: left
 }

.mylength .dataTables_length {
   width: 150px;
   float: right
 }

 .myInfo .dataTables_info {
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left
  }

  .myPaging .dataTables_paginate {
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right
  }
```

Comment: Normally it does show in one line instead of with breaks. Your HTML or CSS must be affecting it. Could you add a more complete example of the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Bootstrap, you can use the rows and columns classes in the dom property:

```
// Yes in my example, my filter is on top right. The length is on top left.
// The info is on the bottom left. The paging info is on the bottom right.

dom:
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6 myLength'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6 myFilter'f>>" +
    "<'table-responsive'tr>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5 myInfo'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 myPaging'p>>"
```

And take out the **float**. Then you should have them in a line.